# Java. Array type expected in lambda

Tags: java, lambda

So, I've got an object constructor:

```
public Func(Function<Var[], Var<T>> function, Var... arguments) {
   // Function is a standart 1.8 class
   //...
   //secret stuff
}
```

I call it like that:

```
return new Func(new Function<Var[], Var>() {
        @Override
        public Var apply(Var[] args) {
            return instance.getAttribute(args[0].value());
        }

    }, arguments[0].unpack(instance)  // unpack(...) returns Var object
);
```

And it works. Now, my IDE (Intellij IDEA) suggests me to replace Function declaration with lambda. Okay, lets do it:

```
return new Func(
    args -> instance.getAttribute(args[0].value()), 
    arguments[0].unpack(instance)
);
```

Now I have an error on `args`:

> Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.Object'

So, apparently `args` now is Object. Why? Is that a bug in IDE or what?

Entire code:

> Template:

```
public class Template {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    System.out.println(someMethod(someClass).value());
}

private static class SomeClass {
    Var[] var = new Var[12];

    SomeClass() {
        var = new Var[12];

        for ( int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
            var[i] = new Var<>(i * 4);
        }
    }

    Var getAttribute(int index) {
        return var[index];
    }
}

public static Var someMethod(SomeClass instance) {
    return new Func(new Function<Var[], Var>() {
        @Override
        public Var apply(Var[] args) {
            return instance.getAttribute((int)args[0].value());
        }
    }, new Var(4));
}
}
```

> Var.java:

```
public class Var<T> {
private T value;

public Var(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public T value() {
    return value;
}
}
```

> Func.java:

```
public class Func<T> extends Var<T> {
private Function<Var[], Var<T>> function;
private Var[] args;

public Func(Function<Var[], Var<T>> function, Var... args) {
    super(null);

    this.function = function;
    this.args = args;
}

@Override
public T value() {
    return function.apply(args).value();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw types? (`Var` appears to be generic)

Comment: @ernest_k because getAttribute(...) returns raw Var

Comment: This code doesn't even compile with your anonymous class (before you attempted the lambda). Method `unpack` is supposed to return a `Var` object but instead returns a `Func`. Can you post *all* the code into a standalone, fully compilable, sample?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException sure, I've updated the code

Comment: [Topaco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52914282/8473028) is correct but I would prefer to solve the problem by completely avoiding raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message appers also in the Eclipse-IDE:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object

I think it is not an IDE-bug, neither in IntelliJ nor in Eclipse. The Compiler needs for the processing of a lambda expression always a [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing) which is a functional interface.
In the case of

```
 args -> instance.getAttribute((int)args[0].value())
```

the target type is determined by the first argument of the Func-constructor

```
 Function<Var[], Var<T>> function
```

However, this functional interface is a generic interface. Java compiles generics using [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) which means the replacement of the generic parameter-types by the Object-type. Thus, the interface is compiled like

```
 interface Function {
     public Object apply(Object args);
 }
```

and this is applied as target type. Thus, for args an Object-type instead of a Var[]-type is expected which results in an error message.

In case of an anonymous class this is different since more informations are provided for the determination of the target type.

```
 new Function<Var[], Var>(){...}
```

explicitly contains the type-information. Because of this args is expected of Var[]-type and no error message is shown.

There are two possibilities to fix the error:

1) In the getAttribut-method cast args explicitly to Var[], i.e. replace

```
 (int)args[0].value()
```

with

```
 (int)((Var[])args)[0].value()
```

or 2) Don't use a generic interface i.e. change the interface to

```
 interface Function {
     public Var apply(Var[] args);
 }
```

Then type information is preserved. Of course the rest of the code has to be adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was a typo. I was starting the lambda with:

```
(Object[]) row -> {
```

Instead of

```
(Object[] row) -> {
```